# Angular : Global variable not changing inside Subscription function

Tags: angular, typescript, global-variables, observable, subscription

i'm having issues with changing global variable in Angular 7, using TypeScript.

I am using a service that collects JSON data from a database through a Restful API

**The service :**

```
export class myService {
  constructor(private client : HttpClient) { }

  dossierSubject = new Subject();
  private dossiers : any[];

  getExtract(){
    this.client.get<any[]>('http://localhost:9090/dossiers')
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log("Data acquisition in progress");
        this.dossiers = response;
        this.emitDossierSubject();
        console.log('Received data ' + response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Error ! : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );
  }

   emitDossierSubject(){
    this.dossierSubject.next(this.dossiers.slice());
  }
```

MyService is working well and i can get the Data i'm looking for, 
then i call the service into the componnent

**The component**

```
 export class tabComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dossierService : myService) { }

  private dossierSubscription : Subscription;
  private listeDossiers : any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinnerStatus = true;
    this.dossierService.getExtract();
    this.dossierSubscription = this.dossierService.dossierSubject.subscribe(
      (dossiers : any[]) => {
        this.listeDossiers = dossiers;
        console.log(listeDossiers); //dossiers [object][object]
        this.spinnerStatus = false;
      }
    );
    console.log('Received data : '+ this.listeDossiers);  //undefined
  }
```

Please, i would like to know why my global variable "listeDossiers" is changed only inside the subscribe function.

I tried using a subject for the "listeDossier" and refresh it juste after i change the variable inside subscription, without success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Place within the .subscribe

Comment: thank you Sajeetharan, i don't understand, whzt shall i put within the .subscribe ?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the `console.log(listeDossiers);` should be `console.log(this.listeDossiers);`

And the `console.log` outside the `subscribe` will be called but won't wait for the http request, you try to print it as part of the `ngOnInit()` function without waiting, however it's only within the `subscribe` that you actually assign it

Comment: Thank you Jojofoulk, i understand, is there any way that would allow me to assign the global variable in order to use it afterward ?